# Bash command not found using swift

Tags: swift, bash, macos

I created a swift function which runs command in bash which is :

```
func getConnectedDevices(lblOut: NSTextView)
{
    let pipe = Pipe()
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    process.arguments = ["--login", "-c", "mobiledevice get_device_prop DeviceName"]
    process.standardOutput = pipe
    let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    process.launch()
    lblOut.string += "\n" + String(data: fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8)!

}// Gets all connected iOS Devices
```

This function works if I just use mobiledevice in command but when I pass proper command to obtain list it gives me error that command not found. I am not very experienced in swift.

Comment: What are those `\"`s for?

Comment: I was just trying to handle spaces in commands as i thought it might be issues because of spaces.

Comment: @oguzismail Still the same issue.

Comment: How is the `mobiledevice` command defined normally? Is it an alias, function, or regular binary (and if so, where is it located)?

Comment: It's located in usr/local/bin/ . It can be accessed as it is in terminal.

Comment: Give the full path to mobiledevice when building the arguments string and see if that helps

Comment: type which bash are you sure /usr/bash is correct and it's not /usr/bin/bash for example?

Comment: I don't know how but it started working automatically. Don't know why it wasn't working earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved by itself. I don't really know how as I didn't change anything at all.